# Load remote XML from Google App Engine for PHP

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I want to load a remote and dynamic XML file from a third party server into my GAE-PHP application:

```
$itemId = 5;
$uri = "http://www.myserver.com/getInfoItem.php?itemId={$itemId}&format=xml";
```

I have tried to load the XML information using the simplexml_load_file function:

```
if ($xmlItem = simplexml_load_file($uri)) {
  // Code dealing with the XML info
}
```

But that leads always to this error:

```
PHP Warning: simplexml_load_file(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity "..."
```

So, I have changed the code and I try load the XML as a generic text file. This way, it works as expected:

```
if ($fileContents = file_get_contents($uri)) {
  $xmlItem = simplexml_load_string($fileContents);
  // Code dealing with the XML info
}
```

I was thinking the two functions get the remote contents using the same [http wrapper](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.http.php), but that does not seem to work this way. I have had a look to to the GAE [URL Fetch](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/urlfetch/) documentation, too.

My question is: Why the first approach does not work? Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you check [`$http_response_header`](http://php.net/http_response_header) after `simplexml_load_file` to see if it is getting any response from server?

Comment: Tried! $http_response_header = NULL

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We've disabled automatic loading of external entities by default, you have to opt in.

Try putting

```
libxml_disable_entity_loader(false);
```

before you're call. This is documented in the [Disabled Functions](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/#PHP_Disabled_functions) section

This involves one additional step: First, you must create a [php.ini](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/config/php_ini) file containing this line:

```
google_app_engine.enable_functions = "libxml_disable_entity_loader"
```

Comment: I am doing this, it seems that the setting is lost during "autoscaling" - as it will only work for the first few requests.