# Zend Framework 1.X on Google App Engine

Tags: php, google-app-engine, zend-framework

I'm planning to dive in building app on Google App Engine with PHP. I develop with Zend, but I'm not yet using ZF2, rather ZF 1.11.

I've found some resources showing the use of ZF2 on GAE, but any about ZF1. I would like to know if it is possible to run ZF1 on GAE.

Could you point me on good resources?

Regards

Comment: Did you try ZF1 on App Engine? There is anything to be known?

Comment: Currently I'm trying ZF1 on GAE Laucher

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm porting a ZF1 application on App Engine.

The first issue I noticed is the need for setting up the cache configuration for Zend_Locale, which defaults to 'File', and must me changed in 'Memcached'.

I also had to create a php.ini in order to enable `libxml_disable_entity_loader` or Zend_Locale could not parse XML files.

In Bootstrap.php:

```
protected function _initCache()
{
    // @link http://stackoverflow.com/a/18971133/898480
    // makes simplexml_load_file() working in Zend_Locale_Data
    libxml_disable_entity_loader(false);

    $cache = Zend_Cache::factory('Core', 'Memcached',
        array('automatic_serialization' => true)
    );

    Zend_Locale::setCache($cache);
    Zend_Locale_Data::setCache($cache);
    Zend_Currency::setCache($cache);
    Zend_Translate::setCache($cache);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the infos Francesco.
Usually, I'm writing log file with Zend_Log, but it seems that you can not create file on GAE. How do you manage that?
Currently I'm working on local with GAE Launcher. No problem till now. I have not yet try a connection to mysql.
Regards